# Kineticjs with image always on top (like watermark)

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

How can I use a always on top image with kineticjs? It's not working. I want to do something like a watermark, each layer added will appear behind it.

So, I will start with an image (like an watermark) and then I'll add the layers, then when I add the layers the watermark will be always on the top (z-index)

```
<script>
    var object_desktop = {width: 650, height: 400};

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'canvas',
        width: object_desktop.width,
        height: object_desktop.height
    });

    //create background
    var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: object_desktop.width,
        height: object_desktop.height,
        fill: "#ffffff",
        stroke: "#666666",
        strokeWidth: 1
    });
    //create group
    var elementGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    });
    elementGroup.add(background)
    //create layer
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    layer.add(elementGroup);

    stage.add(layer);
    stage.draw();





    $('button[type=submit]').click(function () {
        stage.toDataURL({

            callback: function (dataUrl) {
                $('input[name=upload]').val(dataUrl);
                $('#footer_form').submit();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    if (!(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)) {
        alert('Este browser não suporta essa funcionalidade, atualize-o.');
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){

           Image= new Kinetic.Image({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 83, height: 67,image: img, draggable:true});
           layer.add(Image);
           layer.draw();
        };
        img.src = '{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logotipo2.png';
        initStage();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can use a (non-canvas) div with absolute position inside the canvas div.

Comment: But if I use a absolute position div, it will not be draggable :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that every shape (including `Kinetic.Image`) needs to be added to a layer, let's call it `watermarkLayer`. After adding the watermark image to `watermarkLayer`, you can use `watermarkLayer.moveToTop();` so it will appear on top (z-index) of every other layers that you may have previously defined. If you need to add other shapes/layers after adding the watermark, you can use `moveDown()` or `moveToBottom()` on them.

You can see a simple example [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-layering-with-kineticjs/) regarding shape layering.